# Laravel 5.8 : How to send email after user click verify link

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-events

I implemented auth system by `php artisan make:auth` and already setup user email verify by MustVerify from laravel feature

I want to send another email (Greeting mail) after user click verify link. How can I do that?

Comment: why you dont try event listener?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When a user is registered a `Illuminate/Auth/Events/Verified` event is broadcast.

You can use this artisan command to generate a listener

```
php artisan make:listener SendWelcomeMail
```

In the listener you can add logic to the `handle($event)` function.

```
public function handle(Verified $event)
{
    Mail::to($event->user->email)->send(new Greeting());
}
```

Then you register the listener with the event in the `EventServiceProvider`

```
protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ],
    Verified::class => [
        SendWelcomeMail::class
    ],
];
```