# How do I customize an action after a user has verified his email, with Laravel 8 + Fortify

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-8, fortify

I set up a user registration in Laravel 8, with the help of Fortify.

I works pretty much as I expected, except that I would like to trigger a specific action when a user clicks the verification link. (When verification succeeded, that is.)

I know I can specify a redirection url through the `home` parameter in `config/fortify.php`, but this also applies to regular sign-in action. I would like something specific to email verification.

Any idea how I could at least check if the email has just been verified ?

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55204383/8016720

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to Listen to an event, that way you can know when someone got verified and do something.

This is the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/fortify/blob/1.x/src/Http/Controllers/VerifyEmailController.php), so you can see it is dispatching `event(new Verified($request->user()));`, so you have to listen to `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified` event.